# How to run AVD created in Android Studio using *.img files from AOSP build

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device, android-source

I have bunch of *.img files (result of AOSP build done on Linux) and I want to load them into an AVD created by AndroidStudio in Windows. Is that doable?
By *.img files I mean files that are created under out/target/product/{product}, not pictures.

Comment: @m1987 Thanks but that's not what I mean. I have updated my question. Still thanks for taking the time. Have a nice one, sir